# ANTLR4 NEWLINE at each expression but optional for the last

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to build a simple application that is recognizing simple mathematical expressions, each being separated by NEWLINE. Everything works fine, but I don't know how to make the NEWLINE optional after the last expression. This is part of my grammar file with only the necessary stuff:

```
statements
: statement+ EOF
;

statement
: variableId ASSIGN expression NEWLINE+                                     
;

NEWLINE             : '\r'? '\n';
```

Currently also the last statement must be followed by NEWLINE. If a make the NEWLINE optional (*) then I am able to insert 2 statements on the same line, which I do not want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
statements
: statement (NEWLINE+ statement)* NEWLINE* EOF
;

Statement
: variable ASSIGN expression
;
```

This approach uses the `NEWLINE` as a separator rather than a terminator, which seems to be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Solution works, but I also want to be able to insert empty lines so the statement from parenthesis should be optional: statement (NEWLINE+ statement?)* EOF

Comment: revised to include provision for empty lines at the end of the file.  I don't see any reason your change would not work, but (IMHO) find the "NEWLINE* EOF" a little easier for the reader to interpret.

Comment: No, it works, I just suggested to also include it in the solution.